# Can a NetSuite workflow receive a purchase order?

Tags: workflow, customization, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to create a workflow action in NetSuite to automatically receive all items on a purchase order.  I can trigger the workflow on the POs I want to be affected (below a dollar limit) but I can't get NetSuite to receive the PO.

I tried using the "Set Field Value" workflow action to change the "Order Status" field of the purchase order to "Pending Billing" but this didn't work.  The workflow log shows the action ran, `SETFIELDVALUE` was executed but `orderstatus` was set to `F`.

What am I missing here?

Screenshot of the Workflow Action:
[image: Screenshot of the workflow action]

Screenshot of the Workflow Log:
[image: Screenshot of the workflow log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Transform Record action.  I use Transform Record to bill purchase orders using a Scheduled Workflow and I see no reason why it wouldn't work for receiving purchase orders as well.  Good luck!

Comment: I got it to work using the "Transform Record" action, and under "Parameters" setting the "Record Type" to "Item Receipt".